Meaning of 少女たちねるとん大
I wonder if there's anything special about the text printed on the game case (which is called あおり right?) 美少女たちねるとん大. I am not sure what ねるとん大 is supposed to mean. Based on what I found, ねるとん seems to be a inversion of トンネル. Is there are any missing words after 大?

(Source: 16-bit sensation chapter 3)

ngl I'm clueless about this

What's normally called 婚活パーティー today used to be called ねるとん(パーティー) in the 1980's and early 1990's. The name is from this TV program featuring a comedy duo called とんねるず.
ねるとん was a word known to almost everyone in those days, but it became a fairly dated word in the late 1990's.

放送開始から20回ほどは『上海紅鯨団が行く』の内容を引き継ぎ、毎回企画テーマが変わっていたが、とんねるずが司会をする集団見合い企画が好評だったため、途中から集団お見合い番組となった。(snip) 番組タイトルの「ねるとん」は集団見合パーティーの代名詞になった。

Considering that this manga is set around 1990, I'm certain that the word used here is ねるとん in the above sense, but it's not a word that directly suggests pornography. A large part of the catchphrase is hidden, and it's difficult for me to even guess what words た and 大 are parts of.
